# How can I add a newline after X number of characters in Perl?

Tags: perl

I was wondering how can I add a newline character (i.e. `/n` or `<br>`) after X number of characters.

For example, let's say I have a perl variable $message ="aaaaabbbbbcccccdd". I want to add a newline character after every 5 characters to this variable. So when I print the variable in html it will display:

```
aaaaa 
bbbbb 
ccccc 
dd
```

What is the best way to do this? I was told to use substr or a count function, but I'm not sure how to go about it. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An even shorter option.

```
$m = "aaaaabbbbbcccccdd";
$m =~ s/(.{1,5})/$1\n/gs;
print $m;
```

Outputs:

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
dd
```

Of course I think my version is the best of all presented up to now. ;)

Comment: @roddick: you need to get the last group, which might not be five characters.

Comment: @RobertP - you can easily go with .{5} - .{1,5} is *not* necessary!

Comment: using .{5} works for me. Initially, I had dd  <br> as the output but I don't need the newline if the leftover characters are less than 5. I just edited my output to avoid any confusion. Thank you all for your contributions.

Comment: .{5} does work fine; my initial comments are now deleted, and were inaccurate.

Answer (score 4):

I heard that the most efficient way is to use unpack:

```
say for unpack "(A5)*", "012345678901234567890123456879"
```

Output:

```
01234
56789
01234
56789
01234
56879
```

Comment: That's an interesting use of unpack. I like it.  It's a lot cleaner than a regex version.

Comment: Except it doesn't add it to the variable.  You'd need a slight change to make that work.

Comment: if you want to add the `<br>`s to the variable, you must do something like

    $x = join " <br>\n", unpack '(A5)*', $x

Answer (score 4):

Building on Massa's answer, I'd do it like this:

```
$message = join("\n", unpack('(A5)*', $message ))
```

running it,

```
$ perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $message = "aaaaabbbbbcccccdd";

$message = join("\n", unpack("(A5)*", $message));
print $message;
^D
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
dd
```

Replace "\n" with whatever you want to actually terminate each line with (eg, "\<br>\n" .)

Answer (score 3):

In perl, there are many ways to accomplish the same thing ;-)

One them might be:

```
$message = "aaaaabbbbbcccccdd";
$splitmessage = join ("\n",  ( $message =~ /.{1,5}/gs ));
print $splitmessage, "\n";
```

Output:

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
dd
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears you're trying to wrap text, I'd look at something like [Text::Wrap](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::Wrap)

Answer (score 0):

The unpack method is probably the most efficient, if a bit obtuse. The regex method is probably the most Perlish way to do it. But since this is Perl, there is more than one way to do it, so here are a few other fun ways you could do this:

using `List::MoreUtils::natatime` ("n-at-a-time"). This method is of course wildly wasteful of memory, creating a scalar for every character in the string.

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(natatime);

my $in = "aaaaabbbbbcccccdd";
my $out = '';

my $it = natatime 5, split //, $in;
while(my @chars = $it->()) {
    $out .= $_ for @chars;
    $out .= "\n";
}
```

using the "replacement" argument of `substr` to splice in newlines, working from the end: (you have to work from the end because otherwise further offsets no longer line up after you start adding newlines; also working from the end means you only calculate `length $in` at loop start time without using an extra variable)

```
for(my $i = length($in) - length($in) % 5; $i; $i -= 5) {
    substr($in, $i, 0, "\n");
}
```

if you want to keep the input variable as is, you could pre-calculate all the offsets and extract them using `substr`

```
foreach (map $_ * 5, 0 .. int(length($in) / 5)) {
    $out .= substr($in, $_, 5) . "\n";
}
```

probably the most succinct way using `substr` is to use replacement and concatenate the return value:

```
$out .= substr($in, 0, 5, '') . "\n" while $in;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
substr($string, 0, 5);
```

Couple that with some variables:

```
$x = 0;
$newstring = '';
while(length($string)<$x){
    $newstring = $newstring + substr($string, $x, ($x+5)) + '\n';
    $x = $x + 5;
}
```

Comment: 1. Addition is a mathematical operation in Perl, even on strings; you want the string concatenation operator '.'.
2. The 3rd argument to substr is the length of the substring, not the offset of the end of the substring.
3. Newline has to be in double quotes: "\n"; '\n' is the literal string \n.
4. The test in your while loop is backwards; it should be while(length($string)>$x).

Answer (score -1):

Just pass your string through this regexp:

```
=~ s/([^\n]{5})/$1\n/g
```

and you should be fine.

If what you really have is not a random string of random characters, but a text - you might want to use [Text::Wrap](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text::Wrap) module instead.

Comment: the {5} is incorrect; this will drop any leftover characters.

Comment: @RobertP - what do you mean by "drop"? echo "123456789" | perl -pe 's/([^\n]{5})/$1\n/g'
shows correct result.

Comment: @RobertP - no, it does not drop the leftovers, because it does not match :-D

Comment: It won't add the final \n if it doesn't match them; he wanted a new line at the end of every set of characters.

Comment: @RobertP: quote: "add a newline character after every 5 characters" - it doesn't say anything about adding new line character after last 2 or 3 characters if the number of characters is not divisible by 5.

Comment: Taken from his example, his last line with only two d's has a <br> after it.  I took it to mean that he wants to add something at the end of them, even if it's less than 5.  Throwing the <br> in there and trying it out locally, I got 

aaaaa<br>
bbbbb<br>
ccccc<br>
dd

Answer (score -2):

```
echo 123456789abcd|perl -ne'print "$1\n" while s/(^.{5})//;print;'
```

Comment: See other ".{5}" regex answers; you will drop leftovers.

Comment: Bonus points for using a one-liner :) I'm always surprised at how many people don't know about perl -ne.  (See "perldoc perlrun")